# PHP OO: using one instance of Class across files without pointer to object

Tags: php, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to reuse the same class instance across my files as so:

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
// session_set_cookie_params(time()-199999);
// print_r($_SESSION);
// $page = array();
include('inc/functions_inc.php');
include_once('inc/functions_users.php');
$db = new DB_funcs();

// print_r($_SESSION);
// $page['description']='';

$get_page = trim(htmlspecialchars(isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : ''));

if($get_page !='') {
    if(file_exists('pages/'.$get_page.'.php')) {
        include_once('pages/'.$get_page.'.php');


    }else{
        include_once('pages/404.php');
    }


}else{
    (empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])) ? $page['description'] = users_login_form() : $page['description'] = 'Welcome , '.$_SESSION['logged_in']['username'].'! <a href="?page=sign_out">Sign out</a>';
}

// print_r($_SESSION)
// echo '<script>alert("asd");</script>';
// var_dump($page['description']);

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?= $page['description'];?>
</body>
</html>
```

so my variable `$db` instantiates and stores my class object and i am trying to reuse it across other pages such as:
**login.php**

```
<?php

include_once('inc/functions_users.php');

// var_dump($db);

$user = $db->db_getPost('username');
$pass = $db->db_getPost('password');



$page['description'] = user_login($db,$user,$pass);
```

now in the `login.php` I have included a pointer to the class object so i can use it among the functions of the included **functions_users.php** file.

My question is: Do I have to do this with all my functions? Assign a pointer variable to the class? Or is there a more 'lazy' way then I am already trying to achieve?

Comment: You could put the database code in an extra file (like you did with the `functions_users.php`) and include it in every file where you need database connectivity. Including a variable without the actual file where it got defined is not possible to my knowledge.